# Wedge Product Basis for Two, 2D vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

For the wedge product of two, 3D real vectors in a vector space with basis vectors $u1$, $u2$ and $u3$ [just for a simple example], I understand that there is a natural basis for the Wedge product space given by $u_1 \wedge u_2$, $u_1 \wedge u_3$, $u_2 \wedge u_3$.

How about the more simple case of the wedge product of two 2D real vectors in a vector space with basis $u_1$ and $u_2$?  There is only one pair of basis vectors to wedge to create the wedge space basis, so is $u_1 \wedge u_2$ a complete basis for the 2D Wedge space?  This seems odd?

Comment: The isomorphism between the vector space and the wedge product space is a *very* special feature of two dimensions.  In all other cases (including two space dimensions), the two spaces have completely different structures.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

In any number of dimensions if $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of the vector space $V$, then $e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots \wedge e_{i_k}$ is a basis of $\bigwedge^k V$. In the particular case of two dimensions the only non-vanishing element in the corresponding basis of $\bigwedge^2 V$ is $e_1\wedge e_2$ and that space is one-dimensional.

More generally, by a counting argument, if $\dim V=n$ we have that $\dim \bigwedge^k V = \binom{n}{k}$. In particular observe that in any number of dimensions $\bigwedge^n V$ is always one-dimensional and spanned by the single multivector $e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_n$. The two-dimensional case is just one example of that.

Comment: Thanks to both JEB and Gold for the excellent answers.  Particularly, the comment that in any number of dimensions N,  the N-Wedge space will be one dimensional.  In a sense, it seems that it has no remaining free dimensions to move within. Very helpful and much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps a follow-up question - why is it that when the dimension of the two wedge-product vectors goes up from 2D to 3D (change of one), the dimension of the Wedge product space jumps from 1 to three (change of two)?

Comment: In 2D we have just $e_1\wedge e_2$ while in 3D we have also $e_1\wedge e_3$ and $e_2\wedge e_3$. More generally, given the formula for the dimension of $\bigwedge^k V$ you can compute how it changes when we increment the dimension of $V$ by one. Indeed you can show that $$\binom{n+1}{k}-\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1}.$$ In the particular case of $\bigwedge^2 V$ this is just $n$. If you start with $n=2$ you get the previous result. Intuitively you added one basis vector to $V$, so you can pair it with each of the $n$ basis vectors you had before to construct the basis of $\bigwedge^2 V$.

Answer (score 1):

The 3D basis should be even permutations:

$$ u_i = u_j\wedge u_k\ \ \ \ {\rm iff}\ \epsilon_{ijk}=+1,$$

or:

$$( u_2\wedge u_3, u_3\wedge u_1, u_1\wedge u_2 )$$

Thus, you can make a 1-to-1 correspondance with the normal basis:

$$ (u_1, u_2, u_3) $$

at your own risk.

So in 2D there is but one basis element:

$$ \pi_{1,2} = u_1\wedge u_2$$

which cannot be put into a 1-to-1 relationship with $(u_1, u_2)$.

Note that $\pi_{1,2}$ is a pseudo-scalar basis. This may be likened to the 3D pseudo-scalar:

$$ \pi_{1,2,3} = u_1\cdot(u_2\wedge u_3)  = u_3\cdot(u_1\wedge u_2)
 = u_2\cdot(u_3\wedge u_1) $$